# google-services.json for Google-play-services:ads - should I generate?

Tags: android, locking, ads, auto

I use Google play service (ads) in my old app and after updating library I've got an issue

```
Autoclick (dwell timing)
```

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processLiteReleaseGoogleServices'.

> File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it.

At this link https://developers.google.com/mobile/add I might generate nessesary json file but I have to selected google play service: sign-in, analytics, cloud messaging.

What should I choose, because there isn't 'Ads' standalone?

Comment: Were you referring to AdMobs when you said Ads?

Comment: yes, it's AdMob, of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the reason you're not seeing Ads in the link you've provided is because [AdMob is now being handled by Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/admob-firebase). They've made the steps simpler as stated in the docs:

> The best way to use AdMob is with Firebase. Firebase is a mobile
>   platform that helps you quickly develop high-quality apps, grow an
>   engaged user base, and earn more money. Since AdMob is now a part of
>   Firebase, we've made it simpler to use AdMob along with other Firebase
>   services such as Analytics.

Check the [Integrate Firebase and the Mobile Ads SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/quick-start#integrate_firebase_and_the_mobile_ads_sdk) for the implementation part. Kindly check their guide for more info. Hope this post helps.